# Chartkick + Rails 7 (Turbo) + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, charts, chartkick, hotwire-rails

I have a Rails 7 app using Turbo. I wam using Chartkick (+ Chart.js) and put some charts on my page.

On my local setup it works all fine but after deploying to Heroku I get a strange problem.

When I access the page with the charts by entering the URL in the URL bar, the charts get loaded correctly. But when I navigate to the page with the charts using some link, the charts only show "Loading...". When I disable turbo on my links (<a href="" data-turbo="false"...>) the charts also work. So there is some issue with turbo.

I can run `Chartkick` in the JS console which gives me an object containing all charts on the page. In the cases where the charts are not working this does not return any charts so I can't even do `chart.redraw()`.

Again, this is only on Heroku. On my local development setup everything works perfectly.

I googled a lot but without results. Any idea where to start investigating this?

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with heroku after several tests this configuration worked

```
/config/importmap.rb
pin "chartkick", to: "chartkick.js"
pin "Chart.bundle", to: "Chart.bundle.js"

/app/assets/javascript/application.js
//= require Chart.bundle 
//= require chartkick

/app/javascript/application.js
import "chartkick"
import "Chart.bundle"
```